# searching for diffrent items in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find when enter "2" in find what column and hit search my first item column need to show grapes and my second item column show banana.

[image: Userform]
[image: Worksheet data]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
row_number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
   TextBox2.Text = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("B" & row_number)
   'want to know which code I want to use in textbox3.text to find next repetation
    TextBox3.Text = Sheets("SHEET1").Range("B" & row_number)

   End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using the `Range.Find` and `Range.FindNext` methods.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    With Sheets("SHEET1")
        Set rSearch = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Set rFound = rSearch.Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            TextBox2.Value = ""
        Else
            TextBox2.Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value

            Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)

            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                TextBox3.Value = ""
            Else
                TextBox3.Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
             End If

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Your code will also work with a little refactoring.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim row_number As Long
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""

    With Sheets("SHEET1")
        Do
            row_number = row_number + 1
            item_in_review = .Range("A" & row_number)

            If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
                If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                    TextBox2.Text = .Range("B" & row_number)
                Else
                    TextBox3.Text = .Range("B" & row_number)
                    Exit Do
                End If

            End If
        Loop Until item_in_review = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: when I used this code its working but another problem came. when I enter a number or word which is not in rows debug appear with yellow line on Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)

Comment: I updated my answer.  The Find next should have been inside thel "If not rFound is nothing"  statement.  Thanks for the catch.